# How to install sql server 2008 r2 express silently using installshield

Tags: asp.net, winforms, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008r2-express, installshield-2009

I have created a C# Windows application and used SQL Server 2008 R2 for database. So I need to install SQL Server on my client's machine to run my application.

For this I have created a setup using Installshield and added prerequisites SQL Server.

But the problem is: I need to install it silently so user doesn't have to configure it. I have tried a command line code but it not working, it's showing installing SQL Server, but it does not really get installed.

Code I have tried :-

```
SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe /q /Action=Install /Hideconsole 
     /Features=SQL,Tools /InstanceName=SQLExpress 
     /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="Builtin\Administrators" 
     /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /SQLSVCPASSWORD="a123"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS parameter, it is required for silent install , it should be TRUE.

Check following Links.

[How to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express silently using command prompt](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e4220f3f-8f94-437d-bbaf-d9266a7a7cfe/how-to-install-sql-server-2008-r2-express-silently-using-command-prompt)

[SQL Server 2008 R2 – Unattended Silent Install](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113480/SQL-Server-2008-R2-Unattended-Silent-Install)